# C# Universal Windows App Aggregate Exception (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: c#, exception, raspberry-pi, win-universal-app, windows-10-iot-core

I'm developing an app that makes use of the FTDI drivers as described by this github project https://github.com/Jark/FTDISample 
Other than my string comparisons everything is basically the same as this sample.

Currently I'm experiencing a system aggregate exception when using a singleton to parse a byte array received from the usb-serial:

```
while (true) // todo: build in cancellation support
        {
            try
            {
                var bytesInQueue = device.GetQueueStatus();
                bytesInQueue = Math.Max(bytesInQueue, 1); // to make sure we don't create a cpu eating loop

                var buffer = new byte[bytesInQueue];
                var bytesRead = await device.ReadAsync(buffer, bytesInQueue);
                if (bytesRead != 0)
                    string response = MessageHandler.HandleMessage(buffer.Take((int)bytesRead));
                    if(response != "NONE"){
                        OnWriteASCII(response); 
                    }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToLog(string.Format("Exception occurred: {0}", ex.Message));
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE**

During another debugging session I found that the exception triggers after the await in the following method:

```
private async Task WriteBytes(byte[] bytesToWrite) {
        try {
            var nrBytesToWrite = bytesToWrite.Length;
  HERE>>    var bytesWritten = await device.WriteAsync(bytesToWrite, (uint)nrBytesToWrite);

            if (bytesWritten != nrBytesToWrite)
                WriteToLog("Write failed, bytes written: '{0}', count: {1}.",
                            Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesToWrite).Replace("\r",""), nrBytesToWrite);
            //else
            //    WriteToLog("Written: '{0}' to device, count: {1}.", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesToWrite), nrBytesToWrite);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            WriteToLog("Failed to write: '{0}' to device, Exception={1}.", BitConverter.ToString(bytesToWrite), ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

***UPDATE***

```
mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(bool includeTaskCanceledExceptions)  Unknown
mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task<uint>.GetResultCore(bool waitCompletionNotification)    Unknown
mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task<uint>.Result.get()  Unknown
FTDI.D2xx.WinRT.USB.winmd!FTDI.D2xx.WinRT.USB.BulkRequest.IssueBulkOut(byte[] data, uint count) Unknown
FTDI.D2xx.WinRT.USB.winmd!FTDI.D2xx.WinRT.USB.BulkRequest.Write.AnonymousMethod__16()   Unknown
mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task<uint>.InnerInvoke() Unknown
mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()   Unknown
mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(object obj)    Unknown
mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state)  Unknown
mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTaskSlot) Unknown
mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(bool bPreventDoubleExecution)  Unknown
mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()  Unknown
mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() Unknown
mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()  Unknown
```

The "MessageHandler" class only has that single method available and is just parsing a byte[] to string doing a couple comparisons and returning a simple string to write to the serial port.

What's happening is that somewhere in there it's spitting this to diagnostics output:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
```

I'm not entirely sure what's causing it or how to catch it and it's leading to the app crashing intermittently.

I've figured out that something in the steps of comparing the strings and the writing it back to the serial port is where the error is happening.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding a break when System.AggregateException is thrown?  Debug/Exceptions => Common Langauge Runtime Exceptions => System => System.AggregateException

Comment: Ah yea. I didn't mention it here. I did add a break but I cannot load a PDB for mscorlib.ni.dll - I checked symbol servers and it was unavailable. The project target is ARM so that might be why?

Comment: Then should be able to use the interactive debugger to drill down into the array of exceptions contained by AggregateException to get more detail of what went wrong, right?

Comment: I would be able to if the PDB was available AFAIK. http://oi67.tinypic.com/16m7p7d.jpg - The notification window - The options I have after hitting OK http://oi65.tinypic.com/zji4w4.jpg

Comment: `AggregateException` is not in and of itself a specific exception; it contains one or more exceptions thrown by some collection of operations (usually asynchronous). Note that one key purpose of `await` is to _unpack_ such exceptions and provide a specific exception for handling. It's not clear why your code would wind up seeing the `AggregateException` itself. Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, or at a minimum a lot more detail, I don't see how the question can be answered.

Comment: @PeterDuniho thanks for you response. I have repeatedly tried to catch, in various places, the `AggregateException` but have had no success. My intent in trying to catch it is to follow the msdn process of `ae.handle((x)=>...` to delve into it. I will try to make an example the reliably reproduces it and follow up.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Is this helpful? I managed to get a stack trace that wasn't empty. It's in main thread.

Comment: Well, the stack trace is consistent with the completion of an `await`ed task. But again: the `AggregateException` isn't itself all that interesting; it's what's in the `AggregateException.InnerExceptions` collection that you should be looking at.

Comment: What if you stick `.ToResult()` or `Result()` to the end of that line and get rid of `await`?

Comment: @PeterDuniho I definitely understand, the problem is I cannot get to that because everywhere I try to catch it does not appear to work.
@toddmo thanks for the suggestion: `Exception in DeviceConnection.OnWriteASCII. Cannot call GetResults on this asynchronous info because the underlying operation has not completed.
` is spit into the diag until the async operation returns, then it proceeds normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the documentation at http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/InstallGuides/AN_271%20D2xx%20WinRT%20Guide.pdf

And implemented the following format for reading data off the serial device.

```
var action = ThreadPool.RunAsync(async (source) =>
{
  byte[] dataTx = new byte[10];
  for (int i = 0; i < dataTx.Length; i++)
  dataTx[i] = (byte)i;
  while (!cancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
  {
     byte[] dataRx = new byte[10];
     await myDevice.WriteAsync(dataTx, 10);
     myDevice.ReadAsync(dataRx, 10);
  }
}, WorkItemPriority.Normal);
```

As per the downvote I am a bit unsure why that was done. If it's not obvious by reading my responses I was TRYING to catch the exception to unwrap it but was unsuccessful, and was looking for help in that respect.

Either way thanks for trying everyone.